# IBM Worklight - 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

My project build using IBM Worklight 6.1.0.01-20140427-1450.

[image]

First thing I try to achieve it.

[image]

Then I got this error message, `'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found`

[image]

I already search all the solutions in stackoverflow but the solutions still disappointed. How I can setup Header Search Path inside my build setting so my Cordova header can be trace.

[image]

Comment: Edit your question with the *Worklight version* and *steps to reproduce*.

Comment: And now, instead of giving me a partial screen shot, can you actually provide the version number? like this: 6.1.0.01-20140612

Comment: my version number, 6.1.0.01-20140427-1450

Comment: Right, this is a very old version. If memory serves me right, this is long fixed already since that version. Worklight 6.1.0.2 was released yesterday. Download it from IBM Fix Central and see if the issue happens still.

Comment: Direct download link: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/iws_update_site_wde.6.1.0.2.zip

Comment: I already updated my worklight but the problem still occur, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25659401/ibm-worklight-cwwkx0202e-the-websphere-java-management-extensions-rest-client

Comment: How is that related?

Comment: If you encounter an issue and you want help, provide a sample where we, who are here to help you, can see the error. Otherwise this is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer. Delete iphone environment and create new again once more. Settle.

Answer (score -1):

If you are still suffering from this, see the comment in this question, maybe it's the same issue for you: ['Cordova/CDVViewController.h' not found when Archiving in Xcode (from Worklight)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25933622/cordova-cdvviewcontroller-h-not-found-when-archiving-in-xcode-from-worklight):

> Turns out I had a spurious " (double quote) in my Header Search Path

---

Using Worklight 6.1.0.2 I was able to successfully generate an .ipa file in Xcode.
Steps:

1. Created a new Worklight project
2. Added the iPhone environment
3. Run As > Xcode project
4. Selected "iOS Device"
5. Product > Archive > Distribute... > Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc Deployment

.ipa file was generated and saved on the Desktop.
You will need to add more information about *your* project or supply a project where this happens.

Comment: Then like I wrote, you need to provide a reproduction of the error.