# IBM Worklight - CWWKX0202E: The WebSphere Java Management Extensions REST client was unable to process the response from the server for URL

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I'm using IBM Worklight 6.2.0.00-20140825-1637 for my mobile app project.

I got this error message when I try to start my Worklight server. It happened after I updated my Worklight 6.1 in my Eclipse.

```
 [ERROR   ] CWWKX0202E: The WebSphere Java Management Extensions REST client was unable to process the response from the server for URL https://localhost:10443/IBMJMXConnectorREST on connection rest:localhost:10443 admin 61
    Unexpected character: [<] while scanning JSON String for JSON type.  Invalid JSON.
    [ERROR   ] FWLST0003E: ========= Failed starting project /bii-mobile [project bii-mobile]
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    [ERROR   ] null
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    [ERROR   ] An unhandled exception occurred which will be propagated to the container.
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    [ERROR   ] CWWKX0202E: The WebSphere Java Management Extensions REST client was unable to process the response from the server for URL https://localhost:10443/IBMJMXConnectorREST on connection rest:localhost:10443 admin 62
    Unexpected character: [<] while scanning JSON String for JSON type.  Invalid JSON.
    [ERROR   ] An unhandled exception occurred which will be propagated to the container.
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    [ERROR   ] CWWKX0202E: The WebSphere Java Management Extensions REST client was unable to process the response from the server for URL https://localhost:10443/IBMJMXConnectorREST on connection rest:localhost:10443 admin 62
    Unexpected character: [<] while scanning JSON String for JSON type.  Invalid JSON.
    [ERROR   ] FWLSE256E: StatusMessage [severity=ERROR, message='InvocationTargetException:', timestamp=1409814384782, detailedMessage=java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator$1.run(JeeProjectActivator.java:196)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout while waiting for the management service to start up.120 secs.
        at com.worklight.core.init.WorklightServletInitializer$1.run(WorklightServletInitializer.java:134)
        at com.worklight.core.init.WorklightServletInitializer.initialize(WorklightServletInitializer.java:162)
        ... 6 more
    ] [project bii-mobile]
```

[image]

Comment: The "Timeout while waiting" exception is a consequence of the CWWKX0202E exception. The message "Unexpected character: [<] while scanning JSON String" indicates that some HTML formatted error message was generated during the JMX communication. Can you look in the ECLIPSE_WORKSPACE/WorklightServerConfig/servers/worklight/logs/ffdc directory whether you find some relevant exception stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the answer. Create a new Eclipse environment then install back Eclipse Studio.